# Boost spirit get position of matching

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've defined my own grammar and I'd like to parse a cstring (technically mmaped file casted to char*). I can react on every match in my grammar(I've defined an actions for interesting ones) and it works fine, but I've got no idea how to get combine every match with it's position within input cstring. I have to react on every partial match, where each part is defines as a standalone qi::rule.

I found out some tutorials how to get a position of an error during parsing, but nothing which covers that topic.

Example:

```
class MyGrammar : public qi::grammar<iterator_t, std::string()>
{
public:
  MyGrammar(): base_type(main)
  {
    main = *(qi::as_string
          [qi::raw
        [
          (some_rule >> another_rule)
        ]
          ][boost::bind(&MyGrammar::match, this, _1)])
  }
  match(const std::string &match)
  {
    //I'd like to have an position of match inside a passed iterator
  }
private:
  qi::rule<iterator_t, std::string()> main;
};
```

Comment: `boost::spirit::qi::parse` should mutate the start iterator to the position to stopped at.

Comment: How it is possible if the start iterator can be of type const char*?

Comment: yes. if you did `std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "")); after you call to `qi::parse` the first iterator should have moved to where it got too.

Comment: @Dejwi `const char*` is `char const*`, not `char* const` or `char const * const`. I.e.: it is trivially mutable

Comment: Ok. You are right. But it looks that boost spirit sets value of start at the end of parsing. And I'm still not able to get the position of every match (only the last one).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (it's always easier when you add a simple example in code), [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/iter_pos_parser.cpp) may help. You would simply need to use `boost::spirit::repository::qi::iter_pos` wherever you want to capture the current position.

Comment: It is not exacly what I'm looking for. I've added an example.